# Angular material autocomplete doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular Materials autocomplete to autocomplete the user's search keywords over 2.5 million of existing words on my database,I've also limited the search function to only display autocompleted results until the 4th character, despite that my page get blocked after the first user typed character which doesn't seems logical for me (if it was a problem with the large data it supposed to be after user types the 4th character)
here is my Typescript code :

```
  control = new FormControl();
  filteredWords: Observable<string[]>;
  url = "./assets/existingwords.txt";
  public  words : string[] =[];

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    return this.words.filter(word => word.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '').includes(filterValue));
  }
  ngOnInit() : void  {
    this.filteredWords = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => value.length>=4 ? this._filter(value): this.words.slice())
    );
  }
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input matInput type="text" class="form-control" id="idWord" [formControl]="control" [(ngModel)]="myword" placeholder="Saisir votre terme ici.." name="myword" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let word of filteredWords | async" [value]="word">
                          {{word}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was with my else condition in the lambda expression, exactly this part of code :

> this.words.slice()

that always returns all my data entries,what makes the material autocomplete blocks when the user types less than 4 characters, otherwise the solution was to change it to :

```
this.words.slice(0,0)
```

this means that if the user types less than 4 characters we don't show for him any suggestions (you can modify the arguments of slice() function to show the number of suggestions that you want).